# Why does stackoverflow think giving a comment during reviewing is downvoting it?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So I did some reviews, the problem always is, I usually know the answer to the question. In this particular instance the question didn't realize he kind of answered the question himself, so I commented that.

Turned out to be a audit, and MY COMMENT WAS WRONG, because the question was a good one, and a comment is seem as a downvote.

I now kind of never want to do reviews anymore. It takes me some time to research the questions than it turns out to be a audit. It feels like I'm being used by some "if (count % 2 == 0) DoAudit();" rule. It's not worth my time.

How can I make it that I never get audit anymore? Or is the only solution to not try to help the person you are reviewing?

Comment: Anything other than a vote up is handled as if something is wrong with the post. That includes flagging, commenting and voting down. A comment isn't supposed to be necessary if the Question is clear. On a side note: If you can answer the Question, why not do it after the review?

Comment: Its a lot of work. But that should be te solution i think.

Comment: Not sure how it adds any work. Open up the Question in a new tab. Finish the review. Then answer the Question. If anything it could even reduce your workload because you wouldn't have to do the research to try to answer the Question while you're reviewing.

Comment: The research is to see if a question is correct. Sometimes a few lines of code with a short question can seem like it is incomplete, but if someone with experience looks at the code it could be complete enough to know the answer.

Comment: You can't stop the reviews - the best you can do is to detect them (often following the 'link' button to take you to the post will lead you to find if it's a review or not) but the point of reviews is to stop people from just, for instance, clicking 'Looks OK' on everything and doing all their reviews in 30 seconds - which does harm because of everybody had the same mindset, problem posts wouldn't be dealt with.

Comment: Yes, this particular situation is stupid. But in my experience they come up rarely enough that as long as you're passing most of the other audits you shouldn't be in any danger of a review ban, so don't let it deter you from reviewing.